# how to change the paragraph with class name special in a input field on button click?

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Vervang tekst</button>
<div id="divResult">
    <p class="special">Alinea 1</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 2</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 3</p>
    <p>ALinea 4</p>
    <p>Alinea 5</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let OldElement = document.getElementsByClassName('special')
            let newElement = document.createElement('p');
            let node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
            let newNode = document.createTextNode(node)
            newElement.appendChild(newNode)
            console.log(newElement)
            document.getElementById('divResult').replaceChild(newElement, OldElement)
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

I want to change the paragraph with the text from the input field on a button click.
Same goes for all the paragraphs.

I tried above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The desired action can be done with less effort as shown below:

```js
document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const txt=document.querySelector('#txtElement').value;
  document.querySelectorAll('.special').forEach(p=>p.textContent=txt);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Vervang tekst</button>
<div id="divResult">
    <p class="special">Alinea 1</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 2</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 3</p>
    <p>ALinea 4</p>
    <p>Alinea 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple paragraphs with the same class, so you'll have to do this

```
document.getElementById("btnKnop1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var newText = document.getElementById("txtElement").value;
        var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("#divResult p");

        for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            paragraphs[i].innerText = newText;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByClassName('special')` method returns an array of HTML elements but the `replaceChild(newElement, OldElement)` method expects a single element see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

If you want to replace all of the `class="special"` elements you need to iterate over the `OldElement` array like this:

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let OldElement = document.getElementsByClassName('special')
            let newElement = document.createElement('p');
            let node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
            let newNode = document.createTextNode(node);
            newElement.appendChild(newNode);
            let parentNode = document.getElementById('divResult');
            Array.from(OldElement).forEach((elem) => {
                parentNode.replaceChild(newElement.cloneNode(true), elem);
            });
        });
    })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop1">Vervang tekst</button>
<div id="divResult">
    <p class="special">Alinea 1</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 2</p>
    <p class="special">Alinea 3</p>
    <p>ALinea 4</p>
    <p>Alinea 5</p>
</div>
```

Note: I am using the `newElement.cloneNode(true)` method because if the new node is already present somewhere else in the DOM, it is first removed from that position.

Comment: how do i make the code without Array.from and forEach(elem), cloneNode(true), elem?